# Label Size to Fit inside UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, sizetofit

The `sizeToFit` method of `UILabel` doesn't apply in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

The problem is I need some of my cells to look like this:
[image]

and others to look like this:
[image]

What's the solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: use [urlabelname sizetofit];

Comment: Try that in willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: instead of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Try changing the number of lines of the UILabel. Or what you can do is create two separate custom UITableViewCells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizeToFit method does what it is supposed to do in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method after disabling auto layout in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved this way:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:14];
    CGSize textSize = [[eventDetails objectForKey:[detailTitle objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]] sizeWithFont:font];
    CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;
    if(strikeWidth <280) // if the length is lower than max width
    {
        return  30; // normal height of cell
    }
    else
    {
        return 30 + ((int) strikeWidth/280 )*15;// if not give the cell the height you want
    }
}
```

And do not forget to set the number of lines of label to 0 `[label setNumberOfLines:0];`